Not able to get the refresh and access token from xero after 30 min
In a console application, I am trying to create the service functionality which will get the new xero access token and new refresh token after every 30 minutes from xero (once the existing refresh token expires).
But I am getting an error

{ "error": "invalid_grant" }

though I have provided the correct client id and client secret. I also tried to manually construct the API so that it should hit that API but again ended up with the same error.
Error in detail

{ ResponseStatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
error in the console -  Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).

If I want to say in a  sentence then the functionality should get the new refresh and access token in every 30 minutes.
Need some help solving this issue.
Service.cs:
public TokenRefreshService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IConfiguration configuration, Database database)
{
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    _configuration = configuration;
    _database = database;
}

protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var Database = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Database>();

            // Fetch all tokens from the database
            var tokens = Database.GetAllTokens();

            foreach (var token in tokens)
            {
                // Check if the token is about to expire (e.g., within the next 5 minutes)
                if (token.ExpiryDate <= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5))
                {
                    // Call the refresh token method
                    await RefreshAndStoreToken(token);
                }
            }
        }

        // Wait for a certain interval before checking again (e.g., every 10 minutes)
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), stoppingToken);
    }
}

private async Task RefreshAndStoreToken(XeroModel updatedToken)
{
    var clientId = _configuration["Xero:ClientId"];
    var clientSecret = _configuration["Xero:ClientSecret"];

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        // Set the content-type header explicitly
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders
                  .TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "refresh_token"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("refresh_token", updatedToken.RefreshToken),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", clientId),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", clientSecret),
                });

        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://identity.xero.com/connect/token", formContent);

        // Ensure the request was successful or throw an exception
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // You can log the response content to understand the 400 error
            var errorContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            throw new HttpRequestException($"Error refreshing token: {response.StatusCode}, Details: {errorContent}");
        }

        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        dynamic objectsPostOrder = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseContent);

        string Accesstoken = objectsPostOrder.access_token.ToString();
        string RefreshToken = objectsPostOrder.refresh_token.ToString();

        var newToken = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<XeroOAuth2Token>(responseContent);

        //var oauthToken = (XeroOAuth2Token)response;

        // Assuming 30 minutes (1800 seconds) for new token expiry
        int tokenLifetimeSeconds = 1800;
        var expiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(tokenLifetimeSeconds);

        // Update token details in the database
        updatedToken.Accesstoken = Accesstoken;
        updatedToken.RefreshToken = RefreshToken;
        updatedToken.ExpiryDate = expiryTime;
        updatedToken.UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;

        //commonRepository.UpdateToken(updatedToken);  // Update the token in the database

        _database.UpdateToken(updatedToken);
    }
}

program.cs:
// Setup DI container for services
var services = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddSingleton(configuration)
                .AddSingleton(db)
                .AddHostedService<TokenRefreshService>() 
                .BuildServiceProvider();

// Resolve the TokenRefreshService and start the background task
var tokenRefreshService = services.GetRequiredService<IHostedService>() as TokenRefreshService;

if (tokenRefreshService != null)
{
    // Start the token refresh service in a non-blocking way
    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var tokenRefreshTask = tokenRefreshService.StartAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
}


The client_id and client_secret must go into the authorization http header instead of in the form data.
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
    "Basic",
    Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{clientId }:{clientSecret}"))
    );


From the documentation:

The request will require an authorization header containing your app’s client_id and client_secret

Authorization: "Basic " + base64encode(client_id + ":" + client_secret)

The request body will need to contain the grant type and refresh token

grant_type=refresh_token
refresh_token=Your refresh token

 POST https://identity.xero.com/connect/token
 authorization: "Basic " + base64encode(client_id + ":" + client_secret)
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 grant_type=refresh_token
 &refresh_token=xxxxxx


